JPA - Criteria with count and paging in 2 steps: is the result set constant and stable?
I am doing manual pagination with Hibernate/JPA with this:
List<Order> findOrdersByCompanyId(String companyId) {
    LOGGER.debug("Looking up a list of order by companyId={}", companyId);
    List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Order> criteria = cb.createQuery(Order.class);
    Root<Order> root = criteria.from(Order.class);
    Predicate whereFilter = cb.equal(root.get(Order_.companyId), companyId);
    CriteriaQuery<Order> query = criteria.select(root).where(whereFilter);
    TypedQuery<Order> finalQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);

    // get total count for paging
    int count = countFilteredOrders(cb, whereFilter);
    
    LOGGER.info("Order count for company id {}: {}", companyId, count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i += PAGE_SIZE) {
        int pageSize = i + PAGE_SIZE > count ? (count - i) : PAGE_SIZE;
        finalQuery.setFirstResult(i);
        finalQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        LOGGER.debug("Final query(select order with company id with pagination): {}, paging from {} to {}",
                finalQuery.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getQueryString(), i, i + pageSize);
        orders.addAll(finalQuery.getResultList());
    }
}

private int countFilteredOrders(CriteriaBuilder cb, Predicate predicate) throws DataLookupException {
    CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<Order> countRoot = countQuery.from(Order.class);
    countQuery.where(predicate);
    countQuery.select(cb.count(countRoot.get(Order_.entityId))); // we count ID instead of all columns, maybe faster this way
    TypedQuery<Long> finalQuery = entityManager.createQuery(countQuery);
    LOGGER.debug("Final query(count filtered orders): {}", finalQuery.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getQueryString());
    return finalQuery.getSingleResult().intValue();
}

In the code review, colleague points out that:

I am not doing sorting with order by
Between count and fetch there may be more records coming in

I think it's reasonable critique, so my question is:

for 2, I am not using Spring so I don't know how to make count + fetch atomic; even I do, between fetching the page 1 and page N there will also be new records coming in. Is there any better way to do it?
for 1, is it necessary to sort to get a stable result set so that every page's content remain the same? But still, how to deal with this new records coming in?

